# Replace a line of the first file by each line of the second file many times

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have two text files. One is an input file for a fortran program and another is having real numbers in two columns(many lines). If I can replace the third  line of the first file by each line of the second file many times then I can automate my task. I want to Replace NR=3  in file one by NR=1  of file two, Run the input. Again replace NR=3  in file one by NR=2  of file two, Run the input.And so on.
I want to use batch file and gawk, grep, sed on windows. (gawk, grep, sed and other unix/linux commands are available on windows via unxutil). Is it possible? Any help? Example:
first file

```
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
17.01425  0.00000 
0.0 0.0 1.000 1.000  2700.0      
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0                        
 100.0  290.0                               
1    360.0                                  
 310.0 800.0  2700.0 2700.0                   
  2   10  360.0
```

2nd file

```
17.01425 0.00000
17.37597 10.00000
17.73771 20.00000
18.09943 30.00000
................
```

I want 3nd line of the first `(17.01425  0.00000)` be replaced by each line of the 2nd file `(17.73771 20.00000` etc).

Comment: Provide samples of input files and your expected output.

Comment: input file  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
17.01425  0.00000 
0.0 0.0 1.000 1.000  2700.0      
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0                        
 100.0  290.0                               
1    360.0                                  
 310.0 800.0  2700.0 2700.0                   
  2   10  360.0                             
2nd file 17.01425 0.00000
17.37597 10.00000
17.73771 20.00000
18.09943 30.00000
................ I want 2nd line of the first (17.01425  0.00000) be replaced by each line of the 2nd file (17.73771 20.00000)etc.

Comment: No pls don't provide data in comments. Post these samples by editing your question please.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help and make sure to ask well formatted questions with a simple representative input and expected output.

Comment: You're getting there, pretty soon you will have posted a complete question: you've posted some sample input, now add the output you'd like to get given that input.

Comment: I do not vote down as i am still learning. I accept answers which I can implement or very clear to me. I was working on @sudo_O answer and would have accepted as it was very clear to me and would have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's partial guess-work without some expected output but this MIGHT be what you want:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { file1[NR]=$0; next }
{
    for (i=1; i<=(NR-FNR); i++)
        print (i==3 ? $0 : file1[i]) > ("outfile" FNR)
}
' file1 file2
```

Comment: I want third line of the first file to change by each lines of second file. Such that I get many files equivalent to first file but different 3rd line. Exactly speaking for now I want to make change 43 times as my second file is having 43 lines. All these 43 files which I wish to generate from file one become input to a bigger fortran program which I wish to call 43 times using batch file. I will be doing all this on windows platform because of some limitation.

Comment: I could just implement it with my limited knowledge. It Just worked without applying any change. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one suggestion:

```
while read line
do
  sed -i "3c${line}" file1.txt
  # do whatever you need to with the modified file
done < file2.txt
```

If you need to preserve your original `file1.txt`, change the `sed` line to:

```
sed "3c${line}" < file1.txt > tempfile.txt
```

and run your subsequent commands against the temp file instead...

Comment: You need to set IFS= and add the -r flag to read. You'd also need to handle a line in file2 being empty as that'd cause a syntax error from sed, and consider how backslashes and other file2 characters would be handled by sed.

Comment: @EdMorton Given the sample inputs given, I don't believe the `IFS=` or `read -r` are necessary in this particular case, although they are definitely useful in more general cases. Checking for empty input would probably be a good idea, though - the intention was primarily to suggest the framework, though, not provide a fully debugged and completely bulletproof shrink-wrapped solution...

Comment: Using IFS= and -r aren't things you add when you discover a need - you should ALWAYS set IFS= and use read -r unless you have a very specific reason not too, much like you should ALWAYS quote your shell variables. The thing is, that framework doesn't work very well as it requires handling of too many "special" cases - you simply cannot make that approach robust, unlike the awk solutions posted or even, I think, if you used awk instead of sed as the command inside your loop (but then the external loop itself would be redundant).

Comment: @twalberg. If you do not mind please write the script which can be used as it is. I am requesting this because of my limited knowledge. Thanks.